# Using the riot shield in extinction mode of COD: Ghosts

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

In extinction mode, how can I put riot shield on my back to protect myself from the attacks behind after purchasing the shield?

Comment: Usually with the riot shield it's just a matter of switching to a different weapon - the riot shield then goes on your back.  I don't know if that applies to extinction mode in Ghosts or not, though.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to buy the riot shield (dpad on xbox and playstation), then switch weapon.  Then you'll have your weapon out and the riot shield on your back.

Usually I just put it on my back, but I think you can switch back to the riot shield by pressing the purchase button.

EDIT: I played some Extinction recently and tested this out.
I performed the following to get the shield out:
1. Purchase it
2. Use it once (shield bash)
3. Switch weapons

You can then switch back to the riot shield by cycling through weapons.

Comment: To avoid confusion, you'll have to realise that if you can select the shield with the dpad then you don't have the shield.  You'll have to "shield bash" to own it.  You'll see the cost deducted from your cash when you bash.